# Export Python TensorFlow model and import it in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, neural-network

I followed [this tutorial](http://jackytung8085.blogspot.de/2016/06/loading-tensorflow-graph-with-c-api-by.html) and tried to change it for my needs. I have a python file where I train a model and save the TensorFlow graph and frozen_graph, which should have the weights and architecture. And I've got a C++ file where I read the frozen_graph and try to predict an example.

```
// The session will initialize the outputs
vector<Tensor> outputs;
// Run the session, evaluating our "softmax" operation from the graph
status = session->Run(inputs, {"output_TT"}, {}, &outputs);
int nHits = 0;
int nClasses = 2;
for (vector<Tensor>::iterator it = outputs.begin(); it != outputs.end(); ++it) {
    auto items = it->shaped<float, 2>({nTests, nClasses}); // 2 represent number of class
    for (int i = 0; i < nTests; i++) {
        int arg_max = 0;
        float val_max = items(i, 0);
```

but when I try to retrieve the results from the predictions I only get `NaN` from `items(i, 0)`

Here are all the files at github:

- [train_save_model.py](https://gist.github.com/KyleReemaN/419cce525a89f83018bd5ef71ae2316b#file-train_save_model-py) (to train and save the graph)
- [pima-indians-diabetes.csv](https://gist.github.com/KyleReemaN/419cce525a89f83018bd5ef71ae2316b#file-pima-indians-diabetes-csv) (csv for learning in python)
- [diabetes.cc](https://gist.github.com/KyleReemaN/419cce525a89f83018bd5ef71ae2316b#file-diabetes-cc) (c++ file where I load and predict)

Did I save the frozen_graph incorrectly? I also created a frozen graph on command line with bazel, but got the same effect. Did I read the data wrong in C++?

Comment: oh and here is my frozen_graph.pb file https://gist.github.com/KyleReemaN/419cce525a89f83018bd5ef71ae2316b#file-frozen_graph-pb

Comment: Can you import the frozen graph in Python without getting NaNs? Just trying to figure out if it's at all related to language compatibility. If the problem persists in Python, I would recommend [the debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) for figuring out where the NaNs come from (or `add_check_numerics_ops`).